# Create jQuery Plugin with TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have added a jQuery plugin that I have created into a TypeScript file.  For instance, let's say I have this:

#### Extensions.ts

```
(function ($)
{
    $.fn.isNot = function (selector)
    {
        return !this.is(selector);
    };
}(jQuery));

function HelloWorld()
{
}
```

Then, in another file:
[image]

As you can see, Utilities.ts can see the HelloWorld function but it cannot see the jQuery extensions...

However, when I try to reference this file by other files, it does not work.  Is there a way of going about this so that I can create extension files like this in TypeScript and be able to reference them with other typescript files?  Or will I have to create definition files for each of my extension files?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a single definition file or one for each of your extensions - it is up to you.

It would be something like this:

```
interface JQuery {
  isNot(selector: string): boolean
}
```

This should be in a .d.ts file, in addition to the .ts code file

Comment: Okay - so then for extension methods, I always need to have a definition file but if its a normal function I don't?

Comment: If you import the file with the function then no. If you want to use external libraries, or create one yourself - definition files are a must

Comment: What do you mean by import the file with a function?  It is not an external library - it is an extension that i have written myself in a .ts file -

Comment: Great, then ignore the rest of my answer.. it isn't necessary in your case

Comment: But it's not working - even though my files reference my extension files they aren't able to actually use it...

Comment: You should reference a d.ts file containing the interface extension definitions (see my updated answer)

Comment: Okay so then whenever I do an extension in TypeScript it cannot see it without also creating a definition file?

Comment: Yes. As I said before, you can use the same definition file for multiple extensions. You should also reference it, the same as you did in your screenshot